# Backup server files PHP

Tags: php, backup

I'm trying to make a script to backup all files in a server folder with Gz compression..

What I'm doing is **tar all files**, **Gz compress them** and print the **download link** in the html page to download the big file just created.

It works but I guess it works only with from 0 to 300/400MB because sometimes I get ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Any idea to how I can manage this better without using PHP System() or exec() functions? How could I keep this connection Alive? Should I chuck the file? Or What?

I post my script

Cheers

```
try { 
    $memory_limit = ini_get('memory_limit');
    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

    $name = str_replace(".","_",str_replace("www.","",$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) .'_'. date('d-m-Y_H-i');
    $name_tar = $name .'.tar';
    $name_gz = $name .'.tar.gz';

    $backup = new PharData($name_tar);
    $backup->buildFromDirectory(dirname(__FILE__));
    $backup->compress(Phar::GZ);

    unlink($name_tar);
    ini_set('memory_limit', $memory_limit);

    print "<a href='/".$name_gz."'>".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'.$name_gz."</a>"; 
}  
catch (Exception $e)  { echo "Exception : " . $e; }
```